# PHP how to get a dropdown list with countries

Tags: php, html

i'm making a country list for my registration page,
but i'm wondering how to implement it into my registration form.

i made the list in the file country.php

```
<select name="Country">
<option selected="selected" </option>
<option value="">Country...</option>
<option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option> 
</select>
```

and in my registration page i use in my table

```
  <tr>
  <th>Land </th>
  <td><?php include 'country.php'; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

But it doesnt seem to keep the value's in the form when i submit it.

how do i make the value of $Country equal to the option selected in the country.php file?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The first option tag is unclosed, if nothing else, this will ruin the form.

Comment: please show the code where you're attempting to capture the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think line break your code:

```
<option selected="selected" </option>
```

So all you need is to enclose `<option>` tag.

You can also extract country list from any site have it like Yahoo, just go to singup page, then from the browser go to view=>page source.

Answer (score 1):

```
<option selected="selected" </option>
```

should be

```
<option selected="selected"></option>
```

Comment: use a code editor, and syntax errors like this will become apparent instantly.

Comment: also, <option value="">Country...</option> should probably be an optgroup tag instead of an option tag.

Comment: in that case the 'County...' option should be left as is, so you have an invalid value that you can check for if the user hasn't selected any country or has left the select with the default value, in which case you'll probably have a lot of users from Afghanistan (yeah, happened to me some years ago).

Comment: @Carlos Campderrós huh? he already has a blank option at the top. 'Country...' should *not* be left as an option because that is *far* more confusing to leave that as a selectable answer. if he changed it to an optgroup tag, he would not get anyone selecting 'Country...' by accident as it would not be possible to select it.

Comment: as `optgroups` are not selectable, the default option selected is the first `option` (I just tested this with opera, chrome and firefox). So, if you put the 'Country...' as an optgroup, some users will end selecting 'Afghanistan' by inaction.

Comment: @Carlos Campderrós as i said before, there is a blank <option> tag before the 'Country...' option, so no, Afghanistan would not be selected by default........................

Comment: oh yeah, sorry. I didn't realize it :$

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the syntax errors other people have pointed, you'd need to save all the countries inside an array, and loop the array echoing one option/country per iteration. And, the part that makes the `select` remember what you entered before is putting the `selected="selected"` piece inside the chosen country option.

So overall it may look like this:

```
function getSelectOfCountries($chosenCountry = null)
{
  $countries = array('Afganistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', ...);
  echo "<select name='country' id='country'>\n";
  echo "<option value=''>Country...</option>\n";
  foreach ($countries as $country)
  {
    echo "<option value='$country'";
    if ($chosenCountry == $country)
    {
      echo " selected='selected'";
    }
    echo ">$country</option>\n";
  }
}
```

You put that function in a included file. And in the form:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['country']))
{
  $country = $_GET['country'];
} else {
  $country = null;
}
?>
<form ...>
...
<tr>
  <th><label for="country">Land </label></th>
  <td><?php getSelectOfCountries($country);?></td>
</tr>
...
</form>
```